# How to get the identity ID of the Cognito users in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

In my AWS project, I use API Gateway to create APIs that call lambda functions. The APIs are called by an Android application. I use a Cognito user pool and a Cognito Identity pool to manage my users (authenticated and unauthenticated).

In my lambda functions, I need to get the identity ID of the users. After some research, I saw that to achieve that, I need to check `Invoke with caller credentials` in the Integration Request of my API.

Unfortunately, when I call my API, I got an error 500, with the following log: `Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function`. Apparently, it's because the Cognito identity pool role doesn't have the lambda invoke permissions for the backend lambda.

So in order to be able to get the identity id in my lambda function, how can I add those permissions and, if possible, what is the CloudFormation syntax to add those permissions?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what was missing in my CloudFormation template, just add it in the Cognito Identity Pool policy (or policies if you're dealing with unauthenticated users):

```
          - Effect: 'Allow'
            Action:
              - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
            Resource:
              Fn::Join:
                - ''
                -
                  - 'arn:aws:lambda:'
                  - Ref: AWS::Region
                  - ':'
                  - Ref: AWS::AccountId
                  - ':function:*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the AWS Lambda (in AWS UI) which you are trying to fix and scroll down to the Execution role part. You need to create a new role that has permission to access the Cognito Identity pool and sett that role for Lambda and save it.

In AWS API, have you added the authorizer which sets permission (allow/deny) to access the API.

If your users are in Cognito User Pool, there is no need of API gateway, Lambda, etc. Simply use AWS Amplify and everything is baked into the framework.

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication

Robin